# Multiple actions in short time - react redux

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm filtering data by values that come from an input, and, every number that i put in there, will create a new array, and i will store that update in a reducer like this.

```
const handleSearch = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const onlyNumbers = /^[0-9\b]+$/;
        if (e.target.value === '' || onlyNumbers.test(e.target.value)) {
            if (originalDataRecogidas) {
                setInputValue(e.target.value);
                const filterSearch = originalDataRecogidas.filter(({ codigo_recogida }) => {
                    return codigo_recogida.toString().includes(e.target.value);
                });
                if (e.target.value) {
                    batch(() => {
                        dispatch(modifyingRecogidas(filterSearch));
                    });
                } else {
                    batch(() => {
                        dispatch(modifyingRecogidas(originalDataRecogidas));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Now, i'm concerned about performance problems. Let's say that i have 20.000 items, and i'm dispatching filtered data by writting numbers on an input, would that be a bad practice ?¿ Could it crash my app or something like that, could i have big performance issues ?¿

Looking for an answer, i found **batch** function from react-redux, that will allow you to render only once when dispatching multiple actions or something like that, can that function actually help me to avoid performance issues if there are ?

Comment: No one here will be able to answer this question, you will need to measure and determine if it's truly a bottleneck for your application and your users. If there is a performance issue I would suggest using a better data structure than an array for your `originalDataRecogidas`. Right now this is run time `O(n)` on every keystroke, but you could likely improve that.

Comment: Ok, i'll think about it, Thanks for helping !